# This method does not give me back rootfs?

Tags: java, filesystems, nio

So basically I would like to know why the following snippet does not give me back the rootfs partition.

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystems.getDefault();      
 for (FileStore store : fs.getFileStores()) {

        boolean supported = store.supportsFileAttributeView("posix");
        System.out.println(store.name() + " ---" + supported);

        }
```

I get out all the partitions but rootsf.
It works though if I specify the FileStore `FileStore sr = Files.getFileStore(path);`

```
System.out.println(sr.name() + " supports the basic thing? true or false? "+sr.supportsFileAttributeView("basic"));`

 //it works with a path located in rootfs
```

It gives me back "**rootfs** supports the basic thing? true or false? true"
Therefore I would like to know why with the former method it does not work and with the latter it works.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like platform and JDK version is relevant information.

Comment: JDK 1.7 on ubuntu 11.10